# Custom Python Package Won't Properly Install via Pip In VirtualEnv

Tags: python, package, pip, setup.py

I've created a new python package for a project I'm working on.

It has a folder structure that resembles:

```
bin
docs
mypackage
license.md
readme.md
setup.py
```

Here are the contents of my setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'A python client for foo',
    'author': 'Me',
    'url': 'https://github.com/account/mypackage',
    'download_url': 'https://github.com/account/mypackage',
    'author_email': 'foo@bar.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'name': 'MyPackage'
}

setup(**config)
```

I'm not ready to make this public so I install it directly from Git via:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/account/mypackage.git
```

Here's the output:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+ssh://git@github.com/account/mypackage.git
  Cloning git+ssh://git@github.com/account/mypackage.git to /var/folders/7w/qsdf76s97sfsdf7sdf97sdf/T/pip-ovbMpR-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+ssh://git@github.com/account/mypackage.git

Downloading/unpacking nose (from MyPackage==0.1)
  Downloading nose-1.2.1.tar.gz (400kB): 400kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package nose

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/.build'
Installing collected packages: nose, MyPackage
  Running setup.py install for nose

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/.build'
    Installing nosetests script to /Users/user/sandbox/.pyvirtualenvs/project/bin
    Installing nosetests-2.7 script to /Users/user/sandbox/.pyvirtualenvs/project/bin
  Running setup.py install for MyPackage

Successfully installed nose MyPackage
Cleaning up...
```

It says it installed correctly, but when I check /Users/user/sandbox/.pyvirtualenvs/project/bin - I don't see my MyPackage.

I see that nose was installed correctly, and it created a MyPackage-0.1-py2.7.egg-info/ directory - but no mypackage folder with my library.

Consequently, when I try to use the package, it cannot be found.

Why? Is my setup.py configured incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but if you're "not ready to make it public", you can install your package using [`python setup.py develop`](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#development-mode). This is what I typically do if I have a package that I want to use but it's "not ready to be made public".

Comment: Part of what I'm doing is to test the end-users installation experience before it goes live, which is why I'm going this route. I know it's not apples to apples, but it should still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear you are actually instructing setup to install your package.

You'll need something like:

```
packages=['mypackage'],
```

in your `setup()` call. Checkout how `py-bootstrap` does it: https://github.com/splaice/py-bootstrap/blob/master/setup.py

For including `bin` scripts, you'll need to list your scripts with the `scripts` directive as well, for example:

```
scripts=['bin/myscript']
```

Comment: Yup. Just figured that out. As an aside, the [Pytjon Setup Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) is poorly written. Not at all friendly to new package authors.

Comment: doremi: I’d love to get your feedback to improve the docs.  Could you open a report on bugs.python.org or if you prefer send me a mail? (my address is on my profile)

Comment: @ÉricAraujo: I had the same problem for the same reason despite following the official guide. I guess that it would be a great idea to get a step-by-step guide for the simplest user case (I want to share a pure python package between my projects and import it as if it was inside the file without having to copy it each time). Including a project structure, setup structure and step by step guide before explaining what is the wheel, PEP naming conventions and Co would be a great plus for the newcomers like myself.

Comment: Well, the page your linked to in your question does start with an example that uses ``packages=[...]``.